# create one CmakeList.txt file for multiple subdirectories each containg its own src(.cpp files) and include(.h files)

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, cmake-gui

How to write one  Cmake file that compile all my sub-directories each with its own executable?

```
       /Project
            Cmakelist.txt
            /project 1
                /src
                  .cpp
                /include
                  .h
            /project 2
                /src
                  .cpp
                /include
                  .h
```

Comment: Doesn't `add_subdirectory` fit the bill?

Comment: @SergeyA I am newbie in Cmake, I have come across add_subdirectory, but don't know how to set the executable for each project

Comment: Every subdirectory will have it's own CMakeLists.txt, with own `add_executable`.

Comment: @Sergey I did as you said, I am getting error that I cant include_directories(include) multiple times, what should i do, beside then renaming the include folder in each project differently

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Include this in every CmakeList.txt  subfolder

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.2)

project(project1)

set(SRC  "src/name.cpp" "include/name2.h")

add_executable(project1 ${SRC})

target_include_directories (project1 PRIVATE include)

And this in the CmakeList.txt root directory

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.2)

project(project)

add_subdirectory(project1)

add_subdirectory(project2)

...add more if you want

you can also delete the header files from set, it will also work